# Error emitted from the queue, discord music bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, package.json

I'm fairly certain this is a dependency issue but errors recently started when I try to utilize a discord bot. Every time the music bot goes to play something, it will join the channel -> not play anything -> and the following errors spit out in the console:

> [ServerName] Error emitted from the queue: Invalid or unexpected token
> [ServerName] Error emitted from the connection: [PlayerError] Cannot play a resource that has already ended.

I'm utilizing the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "music-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": "",
  "description": "A simple discord music bot",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "prettier --write \"**/*.js\"",
    "start": "worker: node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "discord",
    "music",
    "bot"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/opus": "^0.7.0",
    "discord-player": "^5.2.2",
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "ffmpeg": "0.0.4",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^5.0.2",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "ytdl-core": "^4.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

**If anyone can point me in the right direction as to what the dependency issue might be or how to debug it then I'd appreciate it.**

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't really provide any code, I'm just guessing that `discord-player` gets an invalid query to search for. Perhaps you are passing an `object` or `array` to the search query. If you're using message commands try using `message.content` and when using interaction commands `interaction.options.getString(*variable*)`